# Effective scraping from web into (pandas) DataFrame that preserves the intended format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Goal: Scraping a page and convert it to DataFrame preserving the intended format (python 3).

The data seems to be in csv format and is located here:
'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data'. I tried three approaches, but they all fail.

Approach 1: `pandas.read_csv(url)` --> the dataframe format is all garbled.
E.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data'
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep=',')
df.head()
```

Output:

```
    18.0 8 307.0 130.0 3504. 12.0 70 1  "chevrolet chevelle malibu"
0   15.0 8 350.0 165.0 3693. 11...
1   18.0 8 318.0 150.0 3436. 11...
2   16.0 8 304.0 150.0 3433. 12...
3   17.0 8 302.0 140.0 3449. 10...
4   15.0 8 429.0 198.0 4341. 10...
```

Approach 2: `pandas.read_html` --> `ValueError: No tables found`.

Full trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-07c4c7f7c45c> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.read_html(url)
      2 df.head(10)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py in read_html(io, match, flavor, header, index_col, skiprows, attrs, parse_dates, tupleize_cols, thousands, encoding, decimal, converters, na_values, keep_default_na)
    904                   thousands=thousands, attrs=attrs, encoding=encoding,
    905                   decimal=decimal, converters=converters, na_values=na_values,
--> 906                   keep_default_na=keep_default_na)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py in _parse(flavor, io, match, attrs, encoding, **kwargs)
    741             break
    742     else:
--> 743         raise_with_traceback(retained)
    744 
    745     ret = []

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py in raise_with_traceback(exc, traceback)
    342         if traceback == Ellipsis:
    343             _, _, traceback = sys.exc_info()
--> 344         raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
    345 else:
    346     # this version of raise is a syntax error in Python 3

ValueError: No tables found
```

Approach 3: `BeatifulSoup` to `pandas` --> `KeyError: 0`

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

Full trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-a2a52b487623> in <module>()
      3 page = urlopen(url)
      4 soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
----> 5 df = pd.DataFrame(soup)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    335         else:
    336             try:
--> 337                 arr = np.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    338             except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
    339                 exc = TypeError('DataFrame constructor called with '

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/element.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1009         """tag[key] returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the tag,
   1010         and throws an exception if it's not there."""
-> 1011         return self.attrs[key]
   1012 
   1013     def __iter__(self):

KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [33]: url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data'

In [34]: df = pd.read_fwf(url, header=None)

In [35]: df
Out[35]:
        0  1      2      3       4     5   6  7                            8
0    18.0  8  307.0  130.0  3504.0  12.0  70  1  "chevrolet chevelle malibu"
1    15.0  8  350.0  165.0  3693.0  11.5  70  1          "buick skylark 320"
2    18.0  8  318.0  150.0  3436.0  11.0  70  1         "plymouth satellite"
3    16.0  8  304.0  150.0  3433.0  12.0  70  1              "amc rebel sst"
4    17.0  8  302.0  140.0  3449.0  10.5  70  1                "ford torino"
5    15.0  8  429.0  198.0  4341.0  10.0  70  1           "ford galaxie 500"
6    14.0  8  454.0  220.0  4354.0   9.0  70  1           "chevrolet impala"
..    ... ..    ...    ...     ...   ...  .. ..                          ...
391  36.0  4  135.0  84.00  2370.0  13.0  82  1          "dodge charger 2.2"
392  27.0  4  151.0  90.00  2950.0  17.3  82  1           "chevrolet camaro"
393  27.0  4  140.0  86.00  2790.0  15.6  82  1            "ford mustang gl"
394  44.0  4   97.0  52.00  2130.0  24.6  82  2                  "vw pickup"
395  32.0  4  135.0  84.00  2295.0  11.6  82  1              "dodge rampage"
396  28.0  4  120.0  79.00  2625.0  18.6  82  1                "ford ranger"
397  31.0  4  119.0  82.00  2720.0  19.4  82  1                 "chevy s-10"

[398 rows x 9 columns]
```